# Install PyQtRPT package

Tags: report, pyqt6

I use windows 11, python v3.12 and PyQt6 v6.6. I'm trying to install PyQtRPT package using `pip install PyQtRPT` but pip couldn't find a package with this name.

Comment: That package has not been updated for 8 years and supported up to Python 3.4, so there are no versions available for recent versions. See https://pypi.org/project/PyQtRPT/

Comment: Despite the name, this isn't actually a PyQt package - it only provides bindings for PySide2.